# Law of the Excluded Middle for Mere Propositions

Tags: logic, homotopy-type-theory, univalent-foundations

In the [Homotopy Type Theory book](https://hott.github.io/book/nightly/hott-online-1280-ga0040d8.pdf), they define the (non-contradictory) law of the excluded middle as
$$\operatorname{LEM}:\prod_{A:\mathcal U}\big(\operatorname{isProp}(A)\to(A+\lnot A)\big).\tag{3.4.1}$$
Here, $\operatorname{isProp}(A)$ is the assertion that all elements of $A$ are propositionally equal. The book goes on to treat this as an axiom; I'm guessing this means that $\operatorname{LEM}$ does not follow from univalence but would like confirmation.

Additionally, how would we go about showing that we cannot exhibit $\operatorname{LEM}$?

Comment: You are correct that we cannot prove LEM from univalence. In order to actually prove this, one would need to come up with a model or interpretation of homotopy type theory in which LEM is not true. This is a pretty technical topic - you'll probably want to ask on MathOverflow, but be prepared for a highly technical counterexample. Also, the HoTT book generally *avoids* assuming LEM - in fact, large parts of the book are designed specifically to avoid LEM, such as the section on the Cauchy reals higher inductive definition.

Comment: Ok, thank you for your response.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As Mark says, univalence does not imply LEM, and one way to prove this is to exhibit a model satisfying univalence but not LEM.  To my knowledge the first such model was constructed in my paper [Univalence for inverse diagrams and homotopy canonicity](https://arxiv.org/abs/1203.3253), and is not that complicated to describe: given essentially *any* model of HoTT, one can construct a new model in which the types are pairs $(A_0,A_1)$ where $A_0$ is a type in the old model and $A_1$ is an $A_0$-indexed family of types in the old model.  This new model, called the "Sierpinski topos" over the old model, violates LEM, because it has three different closed propositions: $0=(0,0)$, $1=(1,1)$, but also $(1,0)$.  It's based on the "simplest Kripke model" for set-based constructive mathematics.  Now we know there are many other models too, including models in all higher toposes and also cubical set models that are computational.